# Inserting data from another table - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to insert data into a media table. The data must have the media id (which is a sequence), format (DVD, VHS) and the movie title id which is a sequence that exists another table named movies. How do I pull the data for the title_id from the movies table into the media table? I'm not quite sure where to start but I've listed the code I have so far for the first 2 columns.

```
INSERT INTO m_media
  (media_id, format, title_id)
VALUES (media_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 'DVD', );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of inserting separate values, use `SELECT` statement which will fetch data from the `movies` table. Something like this:

```
insert into m_media (media_id, format, title_id)
  select media_id_seq.nextval, 
         'DVD',
         m.title_id
    from movies m
    where ...     --> condition, if you want to restrict rows returned by that SELECT
```

Comment: You wouldnt use VALUES instead of SELECT? When I use this code, I get an error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: No, I wouldn't, because this *is* the way to select values from some table. Error you got means that there's no `movies` table available to you, while connected as current user.

Comment: Yes you are correct...I was not calling the table by the correct name. Thank you!